# iOS Swift Programming - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook

I used to have a perfectly functional iOS/swift app. After trying and failing to install the FacebookLogin SDK via both Carthage and CocoaPods, my project simply does not compile anymore. I have attempted to go back to earlier versions of my code, but xcode keeps looking for references for pod files, etc.

I have even gone to the length of creating a new project, while copying all the files that were previously there, before trying to install the Facebook SDK.

Now, I don't have any references to Podfiles, but now I have a C error:

```
Ld /Users/joao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/circli-fedsmiwjcccxcnbplfrapflskzoo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/circli.app/circli normal x86_64
        cd /Users/joao/Code/circli
        export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.4
        export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -L/Users/joao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/circli-fedsmiwjcccxcnbplfrapflskzoo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/joao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/circli-fedsmiwjcccxcnbplfrapflskzoo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/joao/Code/circli/frameworks -filelist /Users/joao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/circli-fedsmiwjcccxcnbplfrapflskzoo/Build/Intermediates/circli.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/circli.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/circli.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.4 -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/joao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/circli-fedsmiwjcccxcnbplfrapflskzoo/Build/Intermediates/circli.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/circli.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/circli.swiftmodule -framework SwiftyJSON -framework Alamofire -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/joao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/circli-fedsmiwjcccxcnbplfrapflskzoo/Build/Intermediates/circli.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/circli.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/circli_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/joao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/circli-fedsmiwjcccxcnbplfrapflskzoo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/circli.app/circli

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am pretty sure this error is being called while trying to compile the only non-swift files I have: an Objective-C library I use: SWRevealViewController, which I use for menus. This used to compile fine before.

Comment: this is strange, the error is saying that you are missing main in the project, but this should be generated automatically for a swift project. Are you sure you created a swift project and not an objective-c one?

Comment: In fact, the linker refers to "Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/circli.app/circli", which does not exist. The path exists, but the file itself does not. I imagine that because of that reason, main does not exist.

Anyways, answering your question: I created a swift -> Single View Application.

Comment: Are you using the Xcode Project, or the Xcode Workspace?

Comment: @CalebKleveter This was originally  an Xcode Project (and was working). When I pod installed the Facebook SDK, it created an Xcode Workspace. Since things weren't working too well over there, I created a new project with the original script files, leading to the current problems.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding. Do you have a pod installed and you are using the project? If you install a dependency using CocoaPods or Carthage, you have to use the Workspace and _not_ the Project. If you use the project you will get errors.

Comment: @CalebKleveter I did, but since it did not work, i went back to the project. Since, I could not go to the original project, as you noted, I created a new one, copying only the script files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using device other than simulator, some SDK can only run on device.